# pathogen vim indent-guides not showing

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I happened to already have pathogen installed and running with [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/install/) and [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus), which works just fine. However, when I try to use the plug-in [vim-indent-guide](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides), it does not show at all.

According to pathogen as well as the github for the vim indent guides, it would seem that the only really necessary step would be to clone the repository into my `~/.vim/bundles`. I am aware that the `.vim` file of the add-on needs to be in a subdirectory called `plugins`, which I confirmed. My indent-guides are installed into `~/.vim/bundle/vim-indent-guides/plugin/indent_guides.vim`. I also am using VIM 7.3 which should mean version is not a problem.

To test my theory that pathogen is working, I made a file that would clearly raise a JSHint error
[image: JSHint is working just fine]

Given that assumption was proven correct, I tested to see if the files were loading, using `:scriptnames` in the file I was editing. Sure enough, I see two files there matching the name

```
104: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-indent-guides/plugin/indent_guides.vim
105: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-indent-guides/autoload/indent_guides.vim
```

however, I see no visible results of tabs or spacing in any files.

Perhaps it is a display issue or Janus "overwriting" this add-on's settings, but to be honest, I'm stumped. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The plugin says to type `<leader>ig` to toggle it active/inactive. Have you tried that? You can also explicitly type `:echo g:loaded_indent_guides` to see if it loaded.

Comment: I get the error `E488: Trailing characters` when I do `:<leader>ig` in my vim instance

Comment: I think that @Conner is right.  He suggested (starting in Normal mode) typing `<leader>ig`, without the `:` that you added.  By default, `<leader>` means "\", so try `\ig`.  If that does not work, see whether the `mapleader` variable is defined, with `:echo mapleader`.  See `:help <Leader>`.

Comment: got it. I misunderstood what leader actually MEANT, that it was a prefix for the command. I thought it referred to some kind of delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a `colorscheme` yet and this is what i've added to the `.vimrc` file after `installation`:

```
...
" Indent Guides Settings                                                        

  let g:indent_guides_enable_on_vim_startup = 1                                   
  let g:indent_guides_auto_colors = 0                                             
  let g:indent_guides_guide_size = 1                                              

  autocmd VimEnter,Colorscheme * :hi IndentGuidesOdd  guibg=red   ctermbg=3       
  autocmd VimEnter,Colorscheme * :hi IndentGuidesEven guibg=green ctermbg=4       
  colorscheme default    
...
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check your $TERM variable by `echo $TERM` in bash. If `TERM=xterm` instead of `TERM=xterm-256color`, it only handle 8 colors (instead of 256) and the colors will not be displayed properly.

You may fix to the correct value by this line in `~/.profile`:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

By doing so, re-enter vim and type `:set t_Co` should show `t_Co=256`, which is correct.